# Iterating over unicodes present inside dictionary - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to iterate through a dictionary object but I'm facing the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when I'm trying to iterate through `for amount in totalcost['UnblendedCost']:`. When I tried get the type of the variable `cost` it is displayed as `<type 'dict'>`and when I get the type of the variable `totalcost` it is displayed as `<type 'unicode'>`. I have tried converting the unicode object into dict using `literal_eval` but I faced with a bunch of new errors hence dropped that idea. What is the best way to iterate through unicode objects?

This is my Json:
`

```
{
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RetryAttempts': 0,
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'RequestId': '24f21925-57d4-4eb1-abb7-2ee1211acf75',
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': '24f21925-57d4-4eb1-abb7-2ee1211acf75',
            'date': 'Mon, 22 Jul 2019 12:37:32 GMT',
            'content-length': '930',
            'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
        }
    },
    u 'ResultsByTime': [{
        u 'Estimated': True,
        u 'TimePeriod': {
            u 'Start': u '2019-07-15',
            u 'End': u '2019-07-16'
        },
        u 'Total': {
            u 'UnblendedCost': {
                u 'Amount': u '24.2576848694',
                u 'Unit': u 'USD'
            }
        },
        u 'Groups': []
    }
`
```

This is the program I've tried so far:
`

```
import boto3
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from ast import literal_eval
details = boto3.client('ce')
enddate = date.today()
startdate = date.today() - timedelta(days=7)
#print enddate
#print startdate
result = details.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start':str(startdate) ,'End':str(enddate)},Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['UnblendedCost'])
for cost in result['ResultsByTime']:
    for totalcost in cost['Total']:
        for amount in totalcost['UnblendedCost']:
            finalamount = amount['Amount']
            print finalamount
`
```

I want to access the value stored in the ['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultsByTime` contains a list of dicts. But `Total` and `UnblendedCost` do not, they just contain dicts. You can get their elements directly:

```
for cost in result['ResultsByTime']:
    print(cost['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount'])
```